Fetching data from multiple components and sending them in one POST request
I am currently working on a full stack (React, php + symfony) application and I am kind of stuck at the following stage.

I want to send data from the NewFacility and from the BusinessDay component, but in one POST request. BusinessDay is the sub component of NewFacility.
Once I send the data in the POST request, it needs to be fetched to be able to access it in FacilityDetails.
FacilityDetails with BusinessDay would be basically the same components as NewFaciity with the BusinessDay, but they are read only components to get an overview of the created facility. So the data needs to be read and needs to be displayed once the GET request has successfully fetched the data.
Currently I have a customHook for the POST request:

function useHandleSubmitFacility () {
    const now = new Date();
    const [newFacilityName, setNewFacilityName] = useState("Facility name")
    const [newFacilityStreet, setNewFacilityStreet] = useState("Street")
    const [newFacilityAdditionalAddress, setNewFacilityAdditionalAddress] = useState(undefined)
    const [newFacilityZip, setNewFacilityZip] = useState("ZIP")
    const [newFacilityCity, setNewFacilityCity] = useState("City")
    const [newFacilityCountry, setNewFacilityCountry] = useState("Country")
    
    const { timeLines, setTimeLines } = useContext(FacilityContext);



        const createNewFacility = async (selectedFacility) => {
            try {
                const response = await axios.post('/api/facilities', 
                {
                    name: newFacilityName,
                    description: "asd",
                    address: {
                      street: newFacilityStreet,
                      additionalAddress: newFacilityAdditionalAddress,
                      zip: newFacilityZip,
                      city: newFacilityCity,
                      country: newFacilityCountry,
                      type: "/api/address_types/1"
                    },
                    media: {
                      name: "cover1",
                      mime: "jpeg",
                      path: "files/media/cover1",
                      size: 1024,
                      createdAt: "2024-06-12T09:03:17.272Z",
                      updatedAt: "2024-06-12T09:03:17.272Z"
                    },
                    type: `/api/facility_types/${selectedFacility.id}`,
                    facilityOperatingHour: timeLines
                  },{
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/ld+json'
                    }
                  })
    
                console.log('Facility created successfully:', response;
                fetchFacilities();
                setNewFacilityName(undefined);
                setNewFacilityStreet(undefined);
                setNewFacilityAdditionalAddress(undefined);
                setNewFacilityZip(undefined);
                setNewFacilityCity(undefined);
                setNewFacilityCountry(undefined);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error creating department:', error.message);
            }
        };


    return {newFacilityName, 
            newFacilityStreet,
            setNewFacilityAdditionalAddress,
            newFacilityZip,
            newFacilityCity,
            newFacilityCountry,
            setNewFacilityName, 
            setNewFacilityStreet,
            setNewFacilityAdditionalAddress,
            setNewFacilityZip,
            setNewFacilityCity,
            setNewFacilityCountry,
            createNewFacility,
            timeLines,
            setTimeLines,

        }
}

export default useHandleSubmitFacility

And a context to access the timeLines state in both components:
export const FacilityProvider = ({ children }) => {

    const [timeLines, setTimeLines] = useState([{ id: uuidv4(), dayOfWeek:1, openTime: "00:00", closeTime: "00:00" }]);

    return (
        <FacilityContext.Provider value={{ timeLines, setTimeLines }}>
            {children}
        </FacilityContext.Provider>
    );
};

I have tried different solutions for example  createContext and customHook above, but I could not make the POST request from NewFacility and BusinessDay fully work. I am not sure which solution would be the best fit for this.
